# named: Strange warnings in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, bind

I got these warnings in `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jun 20 01:49:41 pro named[17711]: network unreachable resolving 'pdns3.ultradns.org/A/IN': 2001:500:b::1#53
Jun 20 01:49:41 pro named[17711]: network unreachable resolving 'pdns6.ultradns.co.uk/AAAA/IN': 2001:502:ad09::3#53
Jun 20 01:49:41 pro named[17711]: network unreachable resolving 'pdns6.ultradns.co.uk/A/IN': 2001:502:ad09::3#53
```

Anybody has any idea what `named` is trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Bind is trying to to resolve ipv6 addresses from an ipv6 server. Is your server configured with IPv6?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be enabled: `modprobe -c | grep ipv6` returns nothing.

Comment: Check the BIND configuration. Also check if you have net-pf-10 installed in your kernel as well.